# How can I solve this issue: "System resource exceeded"?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I'm using Access as a database in my asp.net project and I'm facing this error:

```
System resource exceeded.
```

Please guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OleDbException System Resources Exceeded ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155959/oledbexception-system-resources-exceeded)

Answer (score 2):

In your code somehow, connection to database keeps open and you reach the limit. Same question asked here :
[OleDbException System Resources Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155959/oledbexception-system-resources-exceeded)