# VB.Net Interop Error 0x800A0BDB

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I have a VB.NET program that executes macros in a .accdb Access database. Until last week, it worked fine. The macros execute fine when run directly in Access but two of the three macros are generating this error when executed from the VB program:

Error occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0BDB): System resource exceeded.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.DoCmd.RunMacro(Object MacroName, Object RepeatCount, Object RepeatExpression)
   at NicePrintMSAccessMacros.Module1.ExecuteMacros()

Here is the log output from the VB program:

7/31/2013 12:19:42 PM   Searching for TEST 'RUN' file (\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\Macros_to_Run_TEST.txt)...  If found, the application will proceed in TEST mode.
7/31/2013 12:19:42 PM   PRODUCTION 'RUN' file (\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\Macros_to_Run_TEST.txt) found.
            Proceeding in PRODUCTION mode.
7/31/2013 12:19:42 PM   Starting PRODUCTION file run.
7/31/2013 12:19:45 PM   File:  \[server name removed]\Apps\My Labels\Labels\Labels.accdb
7/31/2013 12:19:45 PM   Looking for file...
7/31/2013 12:19:45 PM   File found. Opening Database...
7/31/2013 12:19:47 PM   Database open. Running macro(s)...
7/31/2013 12:19:47 PM   Running macro macCartItemLabels...
7/31/2013 12:20:13 PM   Error occurred: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0BDB): System resource exceeded.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.DoCmd.RunMacro(Object MacroName, Object RepeatCount, Object RepeatExpression)
   at NicePrintMSAccessMacros.Module1.ExecuteMacros()
7/31/2013 12:20:13 PM   Checking for backup of today's database...
7/31/2013 12:20:13 PM   Backup database found (\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\DatabaseBackup\PROD\7-31-2013_BACKUP_Labels.accdb)
7/31/2013 12:20:13 PM   PRODUCTION mode exited.
7/31/2013 12:20:13 PM   Executing routine cleanup of logs 30 days or older...
7/31/2013 12:20:13 PM   Log cleanup completed.

Here is the code from Module1.vb:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Module1
    Dim MacrosFile As String
    Dim Macros2RunFile As String = "\\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\Macros_to_Run_PROD.txt"
    Dim Macros2RunFile_TEST As String = "\\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\Macros_to_Run_TEST.txt"
    Dim logfile As String = "\\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\logs\log_" + Today.ToString.Remove(Today.ToString.IndexOf(" "), Today.ToString.Length - Today.ToString.IndexOf(" ")).Replace("/", "-") + ".log"
    Dim DBbackupdirectory As String = "\\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\DatabaseBackup\"
    Dim backupDB As String
    Dim filedirectory As String = "\\[server name removed]\Apps\My Labels\Labels\"
    Dim oAccess As Access.Application
    Dim file As String
    Sub Main()
        Try
            Log("Searching for TEST 'RUN' file (" + Macros2RunFile_TEST + ")...  If found, the application will proceed in TEST mode.")
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Macros2RunFile_TEST) Then
                Log("TEST 'RUN' file (" + Macros2RunFile_TEST + ") found." + vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Proceeding in TEST mode." + vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Skipping search for PRODUCTION 'RUN' file (" + Macros2RunFile + ").")
                file = "TEST_DB_Labels.accdb"
                Log("Starting TEST file run.")
                DBbackupdirectory = DBbackupdirectory + "TEST\"
                MacrosFile = Macros2RunFile_TEST
                ExecuteMacros()
                createDBBackup()
                Log("TEST mode exited.")
                CleanLogFiles()
                CleanBackupDatabases()
            ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Macros2RunFile) Then
                Log("PRODUCTION 'RUN' file (" + Macros2RunFile_TEST + ") found." + vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Proceeding in PRODUCTION mode.")
                file = "Labels.accdb"
                Log("Starting PRODUCTION file run.")
                DBbackupdirectory = DBbackupdirectory + "PROD\"
                MacrosFile = Macros2RunFile
                ExecuteMacros()
                createDBBackup()
                Log("PRODUCTION mode exited.")
                CleanLogFiles()
                CleanBackupDatabases()
            Else
                Log("The application is exiting because it cannot find either of the following:" + vbNewLine + "-" + Macros2RunFile_TEST + vbNewLine + "-" + Macros2RunFile)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log(ex.ToString + vbNewLine)
            End
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub CleanLogFiles()
        Try
            Log("Executing routine cleanup of logs 30 days or older...")
            Dim file_date As Date
            Dim log_string As String
            For Each log_file In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("\\[server name removed]\Apps\Macros_to_Run\logs\")
                log_string = log_file.Remove(log_file.Length - 4, 4).Remove(0, 40).Replace("-", "/")
                file_date = Convert.ToDateTime(log_string)
                If file_date.AddDays(30) <= Today Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(log_file)
                    Log(log_file + " has been deleted.")
                End If
            Next
            Log("Log cleanup completed." + vbNewLine + vbNewLine)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub Log(ByVal text As String)
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(logfile, Now.ToString + vbTab + text + vbNewLine, True)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub ExecuteMacros()
        Try
            Log("File:  " + filedirectory + file)
            oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
            'oAccess.Visible = False
            Log("Looking for file...")
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(filedirectory + file) Then
                Log("File found. Opening Database...")
                oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(filedirectory + file, False)
                Log("Database open. Running macro(s)...")
                Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(MacrosFile)
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                Do Until i > lines.Count - 1
                    Log("Running macro " + lines(i).ToString + "...")
                    oAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro(lines(i).ToString)
                    Log("Macro " + lines(i).ToString + " has completed.")
                    i += 1
                Loop
                Log("All macros specified have been run." + vbNewLine + vbTab + vbTab + vbTab + "Saving file on exit...")
                oAccess.DoCmd().Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveAll)
                Log("Exit complete.")
            Else
                Log("Could not find the file:  " + filedirectory + file)
                Try
                    Log("Attempting exiting of Microsoft Access without saving...")
                    oAccess.DoCmd().Quit(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcQuitOption.acQuitSaveNone)
                    Log("Exit complete.")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Log("Error occurred: " + ex.ToString)
                End Try
            End If
            Log("Releasing InterOpServices Unmanaged COM Object...")
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oAccess)
            oAccess = Nothing
            Log("Release complete.")
            'My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(file, file.Replace("Labels.accdb", "Labels_BACKUP.accdb")) 'still a work in progress
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("Error occurred: " + ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub createDBBackup()
        Try
            Log("Checking for backup of today's database...")
            backupDB = Today.ToString.Remove(Today.ToString.IndexOf(" "), Today.ToString.Length - Today.ToString.IndexOf(" ")).Replace("/", "-") + "_BACKUP_" + file
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(DBbackupdirectory + backupDB) Then
                Log("Backup database found (" + DBbackupdirectory + backupDB + ")")
            Else
                Log("An existing backup of today's database was not found. Creating backup...")
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(filedirectory + file, DBbackupdirectory + backupDB)
                Log("Backup has been created (" + DBbackupdirectory + backupDB + ")")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("Error occurred: " + ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Sub CleanBackupDatabases()
        Try
            Dim file_date As Date
            Dim DB_string As String
            For Each DB_file In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(DBbackupdirectory)
                DB_string = DB_file.Remove(0, 51).Replace("-", "/")
                DB_string = DB_string.Replace("_BACKUP_" + file, "")
                file_date = Convert.ToDateTime(DB_string)
                If file_date.AddDays(15) <= Today Then
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(DB_file)
                    Log(DB_file + " has been deleted.")
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("Error occurred: " + ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Any help is appreciated! Also, I have not had time to research if this can be translated into a simple .VBS script so changing the code does not require VS. Any ideas on how I perform the same task of executing an Access database macro in a VBS script?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [OleDbException System Resources Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155959/oledbexception-system-resources-exceeded)

Comment: The log states that the error is occuring running this macro : NicePrintMSAccessMacros.Module1.ExecuteMacros()
It is hard to tell you what to do since the macro is not available.

Comment: I am not sure how to provide the macro to you or that it will help to do so as the macro runs fine when submitting manually from inside Microsoft Access. Further, the issue continued to occur at the midnight, 2 a.m., 4 a.m., and 8 a.m. runs this morning. However, it completed all three macros successfully on the 6 a.m. run this morning.

Comment: What else is running or do you possibly have objects open for that database that are causing system resources to be exhausted. Does the macro perform different because the data size is large?

Comment: There very likely are users accessing the database via the NiceLabel program (which would be querying data in the database). Could that be causing some kind of DB lock? The database size is roughly the same size as it was 2 years ago, it is Item procurement data that gets loaded from an ERP Procurement system.